# Unable to start MySQL on mac OS

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I just bought a mac and install XAMPP on it which I later in changed the root account password of MySQL account and also did the same on the config.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin folder.
Now when I try to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin I get this error

```
Error during session start; 
please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP 
installation properly. 
Also, ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: The MAC root account, or the MySQL root account got changed?

Comment: Did phpMyAdmin work before you made the change

Comment: Mysql root account

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes it was working but i wanted to make my database secured so i added i password just like i do on windows

Comment: Sounds to me like your `tmp` folder is not accessible by the account that Apache/PHP is running under.

Comment: Remember, unix is a devil for access privilages. However changing the `root` password in MySQL will not have changed this

Comment: so how do i make it work

Comment: Did you check your log files yet?